# Поиск строки в текстовом файле с запоминанием позиции

Tags: java, строки, файлы

Имеется текстовый файл и строка, которую нужно найти в файле. Подскажите, каким способом в Java можно запомнить позицию, например, номер символа, начиная с которого в тексте идут совпадения с искомой строкой? В тексте таких совпадений может быть несколько, следовательно необходимо запомнить все номера символов, начиная с которых в текстовом файле идет совпадение по искомой строке.

Например, если использовать метод `findInLine(String)` класса `Scanner`, то он только делает проверку на наличие строки в тексте, а не возвращает номер символа. Можно конечно в цикле пройтись по всему текстовому файлу, считывая посимвольно, но это не эффективно

Comment: Обратите внимание на метод: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)

Comment: @ezhov_da это нужно весь текст в один `String` перевести? А если размер файла ~ десятки, сотни мегабайт? Не получится

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью `RandomAccessFile` можно построчно перебирать файл и получать для каждой строки величину сдвига относительно начала файла.

```
    RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(path, "r");

    long seek = 0;
    while (true) {
        String s = raf.readLine();
        System.out.printf("seek %d;  string %s\n", seek, s);
        seek += s.getBytes().length;
        if (seek > raf.length()) break;
    }
```

Прочитать в последствии нужную строку можно будет подставив необходимое значение  `seek`.